# "wouldn't touch it with a barge pole" is used only in UK?

Tags: word-usage, synonyms, phrase-usage

I understand that the phrase "would not touch with a barge pole" is used to say that you would not want to have anything to do with it. Some of my friends told me this phrase is only used in UK and not common in US. Is that true? If so,could you teach me another phrases that are more common in the States if any?

Comment: Compare https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/449300/what-s-the-origin-and-history-of-the-phrase-ten-foot-pole

Comment: See [this usage chart.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=touch+it+with+a+barge%3Aeng_us_2019%2Ctouch+it+with+a+barge%3Aeng_gb_2019&year_start=1900&year_end=2019&corpus=28&smoothing=3). The expression has been around over a century, and is still *relatively* more common in BrE than AmE. But the full OED doesn't explicitly identify it as *British*. And the meaning is so obvious in context that I'm sure all native Anglophones on both sides of the pond would understand it even on first hearing it.

Comment: Americans who don't live anywhere near canals, locks, and barges might prefer *wouldn't touch it with a **ten-foot** pole*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Canadians too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the United States, the saying is:

> I wouldn't touch it with a **ten-foot pole**.